# Permission denied when saving to file as text, a

Tags: python

When I am trying to save to a file, it denies me permission. It raises an error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'BLAH.txt'
```

However, when I do it in pycharm the data is saved without an error. Here is my code:

```
save = name + ": " + "RoundNo: " + str(round_no) + "\n"
with open("Clicker.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(save)
```

What is wrong here?

How i launch:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it saves well"? Do you mean "it runs well"?

Comment: it allows me to save to the file

Comment: How are you launching it "outside of the program" ?

Comment: @Taka Please provide the command the you are issuing.

Comment: command ? i already stated the code

Comment: @Taka For example: `python my_file.py`.

Comment: to run the program ?

Comment: @Taka Yes, to run the program

Comment: i simply do open with then python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113790/discussion-between-moon-cheesez-and-taka).

Comment: As an aside, you should have no spacing before punctuation in the purchase message. An exclamation mark seems slightly illiterate there anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the code into another file and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be following:

(I am assuming that you are using windows here based on your screenshot).

You are trying to save the file at a place where windows doesn't allow to save without admin privileges. A python script won't with admin privileges unless invoked from admin command line. The reason why file is saving while you are running the code using pycharm, according to me maybe that you are running pycharm with admin privileges.

To see in with what privileges is pycharm running, please check your task manager output. Also try running the same script in an admin command line and see if it works.